# how to get result value from onPostExecute into mainactivity

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to make an app in which i could able to translate a copied string from clipboard, translation is showing in logcat but app is crashing while printing a translation into a Toast
Here is the code

```
enter code here
MainActivity.java
import android.app.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.util.*;
import com.sk.translater.TranslatorBackgroundTask;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

String def;
String textToBeTranslated;
Context context=this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //Default variables for translation
    //String textToBeTranslated = "Compare";
    String languagePair = "en-mr"; 

    final ClipboardManager cb = (ClipboardManager)  getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    cb.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(new    ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener(){

            @Override
            public void onPrimaryClipChanged()
            {
                // TODO: Implement this method
                ClipData clipdata = cb.getPrimaryClip();
                ClipData.Item item = clipdata.getItemAt(0);
                if (item.getText() != null)
                {
                    textToBeTranslated = item.getText().toString();


                }
            }
        });
    Translate(textToBeTranslated, languagePair);
}

//Function for calling executing the Translator Background Task
void Translate(String textToBeTranslated, String languagePair)
{
    TranslatorBackgroundTask translatorBackgroundTask= new  TranslatorBackgroundTask(context);

        //String translationResult = 
        translatorBackgroundTask.execute(textToBeTranslated, languagePair);// Returns the translated text as a String
        //Log.d("Translation Result",translationResult); // Logs the result in Android Monitor

}
  }
```

Here is the TranslatorBackgroundTask.class which is on github

```
enter code here
TranslatorBackgroundTask.java
public class TranslatorBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{

//Declare Context
Context ctx;
//Set Context
TranslatorBackgroundTask(Context ctx)
{
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

@Override
public String doInBackground(String... params)
{
    //String variables
    String textToBeTranslated = params[0];
    String languagePair = params[1];

    String jsonString;

    try
    {
        //Set up the translation call URL
        String yandexKey = "[MY_KEY]";
        String yandexUrl = "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=" + yandexKey
            + "&text=" + textToBeTranslated + "&lang=" + languagePair;
        URL yandexTranslateURL = new URL(yandexUrl);

        //Set Http Conncection, Input Stream, and Buffered Reader
        HttpURLConnection httpJsonConnection = (HttpURLConnection) yandexTranslateURL.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = httpJsonConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        //Set string builder and insert retrieved JSON result into it
        StringBuilder jsonStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        while ((jsonString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            jsonStringBuilder.append(jsonString + "\n");
        }

        //Close and disconnect
        bufferedReader.close();
        inputStream.close();
        httpJsonConnection.disconnect();

        //Making result human readable
        String resultString = jsonStringBuilder.toString().trim();
        //Getting the characters between [ and ]
        resultString = resultString.substring(resultString.indexOf('[') + 1);
        resultString = resultString.substring(0, resultString.indexOf("]"));
        //Getting the characters between " and "
        resultString = resultString.substring(resultString.indexOf("\"") + 1);
        resultString = resultString.substring(0, resultString.indexOf("\""));

        Log.d("Translation Result:", resultString);
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "" + resultString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return jsonStringBuilder.toString().trim();
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
public void onPostExecute(String result)
{
    super.onPostExecute(result);    
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values)
{
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}
```

How can i use result value in another class? I tried to search but not solved my problem.

Comment: `Toast.makeText(ctx, "" + resultString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`. You cannot use a Toast() in doInBackground(). Tha's why your app crashes. You can see that in the logcat. Try to read it. Place that Toast in onPostExecute().

Comment: Solved. How to access that result value in mainactivity class?

Comment: The normal way is to use an interface or callback function. But you could make life easier by making the asynctask class a private class of your activity.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing the context of your activity to the async task, you can create a public method in your activity and call it from the postExecute method.

```
((MainActivity)context).yourMethodeName(result)
```

Where, yourMethodName is a public function with one string parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the changes i have made

```
enter code here
MainActivity.java
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
String textToBeTranslated;
Context context=this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final String languagePair = "en-mr"; 

    final ClipboardManager cb = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    cb.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener(){

            @Override
            public void onPrimaryClipChanged()
            {
                // TODO: Implement this method
                ClipData clipdata = cb.getPrimaryClip();
                ClipData.Item item = clipdata.getItemAt(0);
                if (item.getText() != null)
                {
                    textToBeTranslated = item.getText().toString();
                    Log.d("clipboard value", "" + textToBeTranslated);
                    Translate(textToBeTranslated, languagePair);

                }
            }
        }); 
}

//Function for calling executing the Translator Background Task
void Translate(String textToBeTranslated, String languagePair)
{
    TranslatorBackgroundTask translatorBackgroundTask= new TranslatorBackgroundTask(context);

    //String translationResult = 
    translatorBackgroundTask.execute(textToBeTranslated, languagePair);// Returns the translated text as a String
    //Log.d("Translation Result",translationResult); // Logs the result in Android Monitor  
}

@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    super.onPause();
}
  }
```

TranslatorBackgroundTask.java

```
enter code here
 public class TranslatorBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
 {

//Declare Context
Context ctx;
//Set Context
TranslatorBackgroundTask(Context ctx)
{
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

@Override
public String doInBackground(String... params)
{
    //String variables
    String textToBeTranslated = params[0];
    String languagePair = params[1];

    String jsonString;

    try
    {
        //Set up the translation call URL
        String yandexKey = "<MY_KEY>";
        String yandexUrl = "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=" + yandexKey
            + "&text=" + textToBeTranslated + "&lang=" + languagePair;
        URL yandexTranslateURL = new URL(yandexUrl);

        //Set Http Conncection, Input Stream, and Buffered Reader
        HttpURLConnection httpJsonConnection = (HttpURLConnection) yandexTranslateURL.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = httpJsonConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        //Set string builder and insert retrieved JSON result into it
        StringBuilder jsonStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        while ((jsonString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            jsonStringBuilder.append(jsonString + "\n");
        }

        //Close and disconnect
        bufferedReader.close();
        inputStream.close();
        httpJsonConnection.disconnect();

        //Making result human readable
        String resultString = jsonStringBuilder.toString().trim();
        //Getting the characters between [ and ]
        resultString = resultString.substring(resultString.indexOf('[') + 1);
        resultString = resultString.substring(0, resultString.indexOf("]"));
        //Getting the characters between " and "
        resultString = resultString.substring(resultString.indexOf("\"") + 1);
        resultString = resultString.substring(0, resultString.indexOf("\""));

        Log.d("Translation Result:", resultString);
        //Toast.makeText(ctx, "" + resultString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return resultString;
        //return jsonStringBuilder.toString().trim();
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
public void onPostExecute(String result)
{
    super.onPostExecute(result);    
    Log.d("onPostExecute", "" + result);
    Toast.makeText(ctx, "" + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values)
{
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}
 }
```